# How to prove $ \|u\|_{L^{\infty}}\leq C\|\partial_1\square u\|_{L^1} $ for any $ u\in C_0^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{1+2}) $?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-equations, harmonic-analysis, hyperbolic-pde, wave-equation

It comes from estimates for wave equations.

> For any $ u=u(t,x)\in C_{0}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{1+2}) $, which is a smooth compactly supported function, prove that
> $$ 
> \|u\|_{L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{1+2}\,\,)}\leq C\|\partial_{x_1}\square u\|_{L^1(\mathbb{R}^{1+2}\,\,)},
> $$
> where $ \square $ is the wave operator $ \partial_t^2-\Delta $ and $ C $ is independent of $ u $.

> Given an example that there is not constant $ C $ such that
> $$ 
> \|u\|_{L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{1+2}\,\,)}\leq C\|\partial_t\square u\|_{L^1(\mathbb{R}^{1+2}\,\,)}.
> $$

Here is my try. Note that $ u $ is compactly supported, can consider $ v(t,x)=u(t+T,x) $ with $ T\gg 1 $ if necessary, I find that I can assume that $ u(0,x)=0 $ and $ \partial_tu(0,x)=0 $. Then by using the formula of the solution for wave equations, I have
$$
u(t,x)=\int_{0}^t\int_{y_1^2+y_2^2\leq 1}\frac{sF(t-s,x_1-sy_1,x_2-sy_2)}{2\pi\sqrt{1-y_1^2-y_2^2}}dy_1dy_2ds,
$$
where $ F=\square u $. However, I cannot go on. Can you give me some references or hints?

Comment: Apply the fundamental theorem of calculus in time to the $F$ term, then do a change of variables to rewrite the triple integral as the integral of $\partial_t F$ against a bounded function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $E$ be a fondamental solution of $\partial_{x_1}\square$. Then you have for $u$ compactly supported
$$
u=u\ast \delta=u\ast (\partial_{x_1}\square E)= (\partial_{x_1}\square u)\ast E,
$$
so that
$
\Vert u\Vert_{L^\infty}\le \Vert \partial_{x_1}\square u\Vert_{L^1}
\Vert E\Vert_{L^\infty}
$
and
it is now enough to prove that $E$ can be chosen bounded:
take
$$
E_0=\frac{1}{2π}H(t-\vert x\vert)(t^2-\vert x\vert^2)^{-1/2}, \quad H=\mathbf 1_{\mathbb R_+},
$$
the fondamental solution of $\square$ in two-space dimensions. We take
$$
E=\int_0^{x_1} E_0(t, y, x_2) dy,
$$
and noting that
$
\int_0^a\frac{dy}{\sqrt{a^2-y^2}}
$
is bounded, you get the sought result.